# What species is this mosquito-like insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, mosquitoes

[image]

I found this in my room in Serbia. It's not a local type of mosquito that I'm familiar with, so I'm very interested. It flies like a fly but it looks like some kind of mosquito. I am looking forward to seeing what this could be.

Comment: Where are you from? could help track it down

Comment: I am in Serbia, Europe. :)

Comment: This is a dance fly, family Empididae (broad sense; two or three groups are extracted for the narrow sense), but beyond that I can't go (I don't have the Palaearctic identification keys).  If you were in North America I'd be halfway confident calling it a species of _Empis_, but there are _a lot_ of them (and the genus is also found in your neck of the woods).

Comment: Wow,thank you so much,it looks like this is it :)

Comment: @ArthurJFrost You could make an answer out of your comment.

Comment: @Arthur I think Empis is not unlikely in Europe too.

Comment: @Remi.b, I'd prefer not going further than I have already; as I said on May 1 there is information I'm missing, and it's possible that even if I had it, the photograph here might not be detailed enough to use it (the key for this group in _Manual of Nearctic Diptera, volume 1_ [see the Entomological Society of Canada website; they have that in PDF] require at least a stereoscope for effective use, even when the animal is fairly large).

Comment: @рüффп No, the text is about Russia. But in Russian Russia is written **Россия**. In Serbian and in Macedonian it is written **Русија**. Due to its wast territory, providing *Russia* as location wouldn't be very helpful.

Comment: @ArthurJFrost well, you've clearly established yourself as a knowledgeable entomologist on Bio.SE, so it's fairly doubtful others will be able to provide a better answer (without themselves having the appropriate key). I think providing a write-up detailing the family would be a more than acceptable answer here. You could "improve" the answer by discussing typical characteristics to look for to identify genera/species in this specific family and possibly a citation/link/title to a potentially useful key. Sounds like a comment about *Empis* is warranted here, too.